# For which real constants $k$ is the function $u$ harmonic?

Tags: harmonic-functions, laplacian

> For which real constants is the function
>   $$
> v(x):=x_1^3+kx_1x_2^2
> $$
>   harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

To my calculation, the equation 
$$
\Delta v=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x_k^2}=0
$$
is fullfilled when
$$
x_1=0\vee k=-3.
$$

What does this mean for the question that I have to answer here? Is it just: "For $k=-3$ the function is harmonic."? Or do I have to add: When $x_1=0$, it follows that $v\equiv 0$ and then every $k\in\mathbb{R}$ makes $v$ harmonic?

Comment: $x_1$ is not a parameter you can tune. It's an argument of $v$ and varies. $k = -3$ is the sole answer.

Answer (score 1):

We say that $v$ is harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^n$ if $\Delta v = 0$; that is $(\Delta v)(x) = 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

In this case, $(\Delta v)(x) = 6x_1 + 2kx_1 = (6 + 2k)x_1$. As $v$ is harmonic if $(\Delta v)(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, in particular for $x$ with $x_1 \neq 0$, we see that $6 + 2k = 0$ and therefore $k = -3$.

Therefore $v$ is harmonic if and only if $k = -3$.